# IronPython asp.net IntelliSense

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ironpython

I'm trying IronPython for asp.net, I got a simple CRUD screen to work. I've read  IntelliSense doesnt work for IronPython, but is there any way to get rid of Visual Studio underlining all the lines' starting tokens with blue and a message of "expected declaration"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to fix Visual Studio's warnings (in fact, I get quite a few strange ones with ASP.NET and C#).

A non-solution (sorry about that), but what I do a lot, is edit aspx files outside Visual Studio - for me that's [VIM](http://www.vim.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall IronPython and install ASP.NET future releases to solve it